# Inserindo dados no lado 1 da relação 1:N - Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Tenho as seguintes tabelas, `Condominios` e `CondominiosTaxas`, que são uma relação `1:N` , respectivamente, minha relação na model Condominio:

```
public function Taxas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('WebCondom\Models\Condominios\CondominioTaxa',
                          'CondominioCOD', 
                          'CondominioID');
}
```

Minha relação na model CondominioTaxa:

```
public function Condominio()
{
    $this->belongsTo('WebCondom\Models\Condominios\Condominio',
                     'CondominioCOD', 
                     'CondominioID');
}
```

O que acontece, é o seguinte, eu preciso cadastrar a taxa de condominio em um formulário, e quando cadastrar o condomínio, escolher as N taxas que eu quero.

No entanto, na hora de fazer a associação, eu não sei o que fazer, pois o método `sync()` existe apenas numa relação `N:N`, eu tentei criar o condominio, e nele chamar meu relacionamento e o método `sync()` passando o array de taxas, mas o erro é gerado:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()

Eu queria saber como posso isso sem ter que criar uma relação N:N, lembrando que nesse caso, apesar de serem taxas, uma taxa de um condominio tem que ser independente de outro condomínio, porque se um condomínio altera uma taxa sua (própria), não pode afetar outros condomínios.

Campo taxas no formulário:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="Taxas" class="control-label">Taxa</label>
     <select name="Taxas[]" id="Taxas" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
       <option value="" selected disabled>---Nome taxa - valor taxa---</option>
       @foreach($taxas as $taxa)
          <option value="{{ $taxa->CondominioTaxaID }}">{{ $taxa->Taxa }}</option>
       @endforeach
     </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

As taxas chegam da seguinte maneira na controller:

```
array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
]
```

Comment: Você deverá então cadastrar uma taxa para cada condomínio e isso se tem que fazer via codificação, é uma regra própria independente de como o `Laravel` vai gravar os dados da relação.